# Eclipse Plugin: *TabGroup cannot be found by xx.ui

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm writing 2 eclipse plugins: xx.launching and xx.ui

I wrote a custom debug configuration. When I open Debug Configuration manager, I can see my new configuration "MyConfiguration". But when I try to add a new configuration of MyConfiguration I receive an Error:

**Plug-in xx.ui was unable to load class xx.ui.launcher.MyApplicationTabGroup**

In my plugin.xml of my plugins xx.launching and xx.ui I have this lines:

xx.launching

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.debug.core.launchConfigurationTypes">
      <launchConfigurationType
            delegate="xx.launching.MyApplicationLaunchConfigurationDelegate"
            id="xx.launching.MyApplication"
            modes="debug"
            ...>
      </launchConfigurationType>
      ...
   </extension>
```

xx.ui

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchConfigurationTabGroups">
      <launchConfigurationTabGroup
            type="xx.launching.MyApplication"
            class="xx.ui.launcher.MyApplicationTabGroup"
            ...>
      </launchConfigurationTabGroup>
      ...
   </extension>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchConfigurationTypeImages">
      <launchConfigurationTypeImage
            icon="$nl$/icons/my.gif"
            configTypeID="xx.launching.MyApplication"
            ...>
      </launchConfigurationTypeImage>
      ..
   </extension>
```

Class xx.ui.launcher.MyApplicationTabGroup really exists

I really can see this icon in Debug Configurations list

What did I wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `MyApplicationTabGroup` implement `ILaunchConfigurationTabGroup`? Does it have a public no arguments constructor? Is it in xx.ui plugin?

Comment: greg-449, thank you very much for your answer. Now it works. I didn't find the answer why my plugin didn't work. In fact, I wrote my plugin correctly. When I reinstalled eclipse, everything worked without any problem